# Deleting object from NSFetchedResultsControllers across Tabs not saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I set up a UITableViewController that has 2 views, I got each view to load different data housed in the same core data model. But now when I try to execute a deletion within one of the 2 tables it doesn't seem to save it. The code is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSManagedObject* itemToDelete = 
        [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.context deleteObject:itemToDelete];
    }
  }
}
```

This worked fine until I added the second view controller, in the app delegate Im setting the NSManagedObjectContext for both view controllers that the tab view uses, then each is loaded the same using the respected NSEntityDescription and uses the same code to delete.

My guess is theres a problem sharing the contexts from the app delegate or something, but I'm not sure what other option I have....

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem sharing an `NSManagedObjectContext` across two objects that only interact with it on the main thread. Make sure that each of your fetched results controllers has its `delegate` property set to its respective view controller, and that you're adequately handling `controllerDidChangeContent:` (This can be as simple as calling `reloadData` on the appropriate table view).

Comment: well i pretty much kept the boilerplate code from apple in there for the controllerDidChangeContent method which was: [self.tableView endUpdates]; ... and this worked when I was only dealing with one table view and NSFetchedResultsController. When I delete the cells they do get removed, but if I close the app and reopen it they come back, so its like its not being committed or something.

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case, call `save` on your managed object context in  `applicationWillResignActive:` or somewhere else convenient. Until then, none of your changes are committed to the backing store.

Comment: ah ok! thank you very much ill try that later on today, do you have any idea why this would of been working (without calling save) when I was only using one table view and NSFetchedResultsController? I think I read somewhere that it commits on its own at different points, maybe now because there are 2 entities being dealt with that doesnt work? Just curious!